# Declaring a generic type parameter on an extension

Tags: swift, generics

In the following example, I'm defining a function to unpack an array of boxes into their values:

```
struct Box {
    let value : String
}

extension Array where Element == Box {
    func unpack() -> [String] {
        self.map { $0.value }
    }
}

let boxes = [ Box( value: "a" ), Box( value: "b" ) ]
let values = boxes.unpack()
```

That works great, but notice that the `Box` needs to be a concrete type with a non-generic value property. When we try to make `Box` unpacking generic, we run into issues:

```
struct Box<V> {
    let value : V
}

extension Array<V> where Element == Box<V> { // Illegal
    func unpack() -> [V] {
        self.map { $0.value }
    }
}

let boxes = [ Box( value: "a" ), Box( value: "b" ) ]
let values = boxes.unpack()
```

There does not appear to be a way to declare a generic type parameter on a where-bound type extension.  For this to work, I'd need some way to declare `<V>` such that I can reference it when specifying the where clause.

Is there any way to get this done in Swift 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is a generic method. Just move your constraints to the method:

---

```
extension Sequence {
    func unpack<V>() -> [V] where Element == Box<V> { map(\.value) }
}
```

---

```
let boxes = [Box(value: "a"), Box(value: "b")]
let values = boxes.unpack()
```

edit/update:

If you want to constrain it at the extension level what you need is a protocol and constrain the collection element to it:

```
protocol Valued {
    associatedtype Value
    var value: Value { get }
}

extension Sequence where Element: Valued {
    var values: [Element.Value] { map(\.value) }
}

struct Box<V>: Valued {
    let value : V
}

let boxes = [Box(value: "a"), Box(value: "b")]
let values = boxes.values  // ["a", "b"]
```

Comment: why is it needed to explicitly set the resulting type? seems to work fine without it

Comment: @NewDev yes that's true in this case

Comment: @LeoDabus Excellent, this is a great solution. But I suppose this means that the language indeed does not support extension-level where contraints based on an associated type's generic type?

Comment: AFAIK there is no support for generic constrain on extension level.